# How can i update label text by pressing button

Tags: python, button, label, kivy

I have a question that i can't seem to find an anwser.
I have this label:

```
l = Label(text='Some Text', font_size=100)
```

I have also binded text input to 'l' that looks like this:

```
t = TextInput(font_size=80, size_hint_y=None, height=200, text='Time', halign='right')
t.bind(text=l.setter('text'))
```

So when i type something to my text input box, it instantly updates the label and shows result on screen.
But i want to update that text only when user presses 'Add' button.
I am new to kivy and i am still experiment with it.
Any help would be great.
Thanks!

@edit here is my code:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Gacut/d765231c2696831af8c8a3315fdabbfd/raw/e1bdcdd8aca588b1c9268e76f7a47fa7576d54cb/gistfile1.txt

and what i am trying to do, is this kind of app, but for android:

https://wumpa.app/

Comment: Did you search for answers?

Comment: Actually i did, but none of the anwsers was helpfull in my specific subject.

Comment: So what can you not do? Do you know how to bind a function to run when the user presses the Add button? Do you know how to make that function change the label text? Please provide a minimal runnable example demonstrating the components at the point you get stuck.

Comment: I have added my code and explanation, what i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
t.bind(text=l.setter('text'))
```

will do exactly what you describe, so that is not what you want. Instead, use the `Button` `on_release` property to call a method that does what you want. The simplest way to do that is to save references to the `Widgets` involved (`t` and `lista`), and use those references in the new method. Like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class WumpaTime(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        title = Label(text='Wumpa Time Countdown', size_hint_y=None, height=100, )
        self.t = TextInput(font_size=80, size_hint_y=None, height=200, halign='right')
        self.lista = Label(font_size=100)
        box = BoxLayout()
        box2 = BoxLayout()
        bremove = Button(text="Remove", size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 100))
        badd = Button(text="Add", size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 200), on_release=self.update_label)

        #t.bind(text=lista.setter('text'))

        box.add_widget(self.t)
        box.add_widget(badd)
        layout.add_widget(title)
        layout.add_widget(self.lista)
        layout.add_widget(box)

        return layout

    def update_label(self, button_instance):
        self.lista.text = self.t.text


WumpaTime().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I was aware that this function should do what i want, but i didn't know how to make that argument to a button.

This is great! Thanks again!